# Vector Autoregressive Models for Multivariate Time Series : Trend and Seasonality

Tags: r, time-series

I have 3 time series and I want to predict future values for each of them.
I am using [VARS](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/vars/vars.pdf)! Package in R.

So this is the approach:

1. Decompose multiplicative time series and take out the trend, seasonality, and Random part.

   ```
   time_series1_components = decompose(time_series1,type="mult")
   ```

Do this for all the time series.

2. Apply the VAR Model on the random parts and predict the future values:

   ```
   random_part1 = time_series1_components$random
   random_part2 = time_series2_components$random
   random_part3 = time_series3_components$random
   merged_df = ts.union(random_part1, random_part2,random_part3, dframe = TRUE)
   merged_mat <- data.matrix(merged_df)
   merged_mat = na.exclude(merged_mat)
   checklag = VARselect(merged_mat)
   EstimateModel=VAR(merged_mat, p = 2, type = "const", season = NULL, exogen = NULL)
   summary(EstimateModel)
   roots(EstimateModel)
   predict(EstimateModel)`
   ```
3. Now, I should combine the predicted values of the random part with the trend and seasonality. And Plot a graph showing the past values and predicted values (highlighted separately).
   How can I achieve this?
   Any pointers will be helpful.

Comment: I don't know the `VARS` package, but you might take a look at the `forecast` package, and maybe `auto.arima` followed by `forecast` in particular, as another, less-labor-intensive way to do this.

Comment: Thanks for your quick response. The future values of time_series1 is affected by past values of itself as well as past values of time_seres2 and time_series3. So i think i need to use Vector Autoregresive Model. I don't see this in Forecast package. Correct me if i am wrong.

Comment: No, you're right, `forecast` does not include any functionality for VAR models.